# Wordpress based ajax form submission not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Basically I am beginner to WordPress and ajax and I am trying to make a custom newsletter with Wordpress using ajax method. It seems something is wrong with my code which I have been trying to sort for quite while. any help would be appreciated.

front page code:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
                    <div class="newsletter" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
        <h2>Newsletter</h2>
        <div class="form-element">
          <input type="text" class="input-element" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
          <span class="email-message" id="email_msg"></span>
           <button class="btn form-btn" name="submit" value='Submit' id="submit" type="button">Subscribe</button>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="messageDiv"></div>
                </form>
```

ajax:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#myform').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   jQuery.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    type : "post",
    data : jQuery('#myform').serialize(),
    url : my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    success:function(data)
    {
        jQuery('.messageDiv').html(data.message);
    }

   });
    
});
});
    </script>
```

function.php:

```
function my_enqueue() {
   
      wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );



if(isset($_POST['email'])){

    global $wpdb;

    $email = $_POST['email'];

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "blogger", 3306);

$table_name ='newletter';

$sql=$wpdb->insert("newletter", array("email" =>$email)); 

if($rowResult == 1){
    echo json_encode(array('message' => '<h1>form submit sucesss</h1>', 'status'=> 1 ));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('message' => '<h1>error submission</h1>', 'status'=> 0 ));
}
die;
}
```

Comment: A better description of what isn't working as you want and what it should be doing would help.  Are there any errors?  Does it show unexpected results?